# Regex greedy match selects entire line

Tags: java, regex

For a Java application, I have the following string:`/a/b/first/one.js, /a/b/second/two.js, /a/b/third/three.html`

I want to select the last path (`/a/b/third/three.html`) and have this regex expression: `/a/b/(.*?)\.html`, but it selects the entire line.

How can I get regex to stop matching the entire line and just select part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this tempered greedy pattern using a negative lookahead for this case:

```
/a/b/(?:(?!/a/b/).)*\.html
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ChP1cC/1)

Take note of `(?:(?!/a/b/).)*` which matches 0 or more of any character that don't have `/a/b/` at next position. This negative lookahead is asserted for every character.

Answer (score 2):

You can match non-whitespace (or whatever delimiter you want to negate) instead of `.` so it doesn't spill into the next one:

```
/a/b/(\S*)\.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this was helpful.